# Error on Celery with Pickle Serialization

Tags: python, flask, celery, pickle, kombu

I'm doing a flask system, and I'm need to use pickle serialization, since it's not JSON serializated.

Error Message:

> kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

[Full error](https://gist.github.com/madpin/ed0ac369ef6d9fe921f02a73c70f6ae7)

The [route](https://gitlab.com/madpin/daftbot/blob/master/daftbot/routes/api/routes.py) file calls for the celery function:

```
def listing():
    ret = []
    listings = get_sharing_route(22)
    for listing in listings:
        task = daft2db.apply_async((listing, None))
        ret.append(str(task))
        break

    return jsonify({'code': ret})
```

Listing is not JSON serializable, so I use the function

```
@celery.task(serializer='pickle')
def daft2db(listing, pub_trans_alert):
    return 0
```

from my [daft2db](https://gitlab.com/madpin/daftbot/blob/master/daftbot/scripts/daft2db.py) file.

If you need more information let me know.
I'm really lost here.